# FatsFs, eeprom energy consumption

Tags: embedded, texas-instruments, flash-memory, fatfs

I am working on TI MCU(cc1310), I want to save data in the internal flash, I have few questions about using the flash directory, or external eeprom.

1. Using the flash can causes greater power consumption the using
   external eeprom memory?
2. Using FatFs could cause more power consumption compared to
   writing directly to the flash?

Comment: I don't really see any programming questions here. I would imagine the answer to your question is found in the datasheet of the mentioned part.

Comment: Use a FatWahtever with such a little MCU I think it is a mess. BTW regarding power consumption you should refer to manual, but the code must be taken into account.